# Nginx проксирование запросов к апи и фронтенду

Tags: nginx

У меня есть три дев-сервера, два из них API (должны находится по url: /api/*), один это дев-сервер фронт-приложения.
Я хочу что бы nginx проксировал все запросы /api/* к API-серверам, а все остальные (типа как путь по умолчанию) запросы проксировались к фронт-серверу.

Как правильно написать правила?

```
http {
    upstream frontend {
        server 192.168.160.6:3000;
    }

    upstream api_users {
        server 192.168.160.4:8081;
    }

    upstream api_docs {
        server 192.168.160.5:8082;
    }

    server {
        listen: 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /api/users {
            proxy_pass   http://api_users;
        }

        location /api/docs {
            proxy_pass   http://api_docs;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://frontend;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы их уже написали и показали в тексте вопроса. В чём проблема?

Comment: Nginx не проксирует. Добавил проверки в оригинальный вопрос.

Comment: У вас во-первых неправильно написан listen, непонятный пробел после двоеточия. Во-вторых, в конфиге порт 80, а в примере 8080

Comment: Спасибо за участие, да я все верно настроил изначально, путаница с портами из-за того, что я запускаю это в докере (делаю экспоуз порта на 8080) поэтому извините за эту ошибку, в своем же ответе указал что конфиг корректен (listen исправил)

Comment: @andreymal если не сложно проголосуйте за ответ - так как я понял что конфиг написал корректный в плане локейшенов и проксирования

Спасибо что подтвердили корретность конфига

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно конфиг приведен верный, это у меня были проблемы с сетевыми запросами.

Вот корректный конфиг:

```
http {
    upstream frontend {
        server 192.168.160.6:3000;
    }

    upstream api_users {
        server 192.168.160.4:8081;
    }

    upstream api_docs {
        server 192.168.160.5:8082;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /api/users {
            proxy_pass   http://api_users;
        }

        location /api/docs {
            proxy_pass   http://api_docs;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://frontend;
        }
    }
}
```